# Can do transaction control on multiple distributed data destination Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, transactions, rollback

I have the case write data to multiple data destination in nodejs

```
writeToMySql(data); //Step 1
postRestApi(data);  //Step 2
writeToSqlServer(data); //Step 3
```

So the problems is data destination is distributed. I want to do something like "Transaction", if any step in 3 step fail, all 1,2,3 is rollback

But the Step 2 is rest Api, if data are posted to Api, I cannot roll back because the data is go in another  server/ services;

So is there some way to do this concept? Thank everyone;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, it is not something supported by Node JS and other "modern" software development platforms.   You would need to rely on older techniques like sagas which would mean the development overhead of detecting and rolling back the transactions programmatically.

but it is important to remember that this is not a language thing so much as a platform thing.   For example HTTP is not transactional, so if you implement REST style API on HTTP, you do not get the other enterprise distributed computing features.  If you implemented the REST style with SOAP or CORBA (which was quite common), for example, then yes, features like XA and others are part of those protocols.

While this is slowly changing, many of the distributed computing features developed in the 1980 and 1990 such as distributed transaction management and security/identity propagation, were not included in "modern" software development due to a lack of awareness.  These traditional features are slowly being included in "modern" software development as the proponents gain more experience in the problem space.

Answer (score 0):

There's no complete, reliable way to do what you're asking. It's the nature of distributed systems (systems that don't share a single, reliable transaction boundary) that one cannot possibly, under all circumstances, provide that same guarantees as a centralized system (e.g. the ACID guarantees provided by a DBMS).

However there are some useful solution patterns that help make the problem more manageable and less acute. Those include Two-Phase Commit, Saga, and Paxos. There are many resources available for each.

The details of the above patterns depend greatly on the behavior of the services / APIs that're involved in your distributed transaction, so it's not likely you'll find any kind of prebuilt solution, but you may find a framework or some helpers that make the task less a little less onerous.